# Search for specified devices on Rpi with bluepy

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm working with BLE on raspberry pi right now and I'm using bluepy library for python.
Scanning for devices works fine, but I want to find just few beacon devices without wasting time for searching all other devices available nearby.
In other words - I have a list of my beacons addresses and I want to check if any of them are in area. Can I simply walk throw that list and check if this specific device is in area to avoid time consuming scanning all devices?

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood your question, but when the RPi scans for devices, what it is doing is listening for advertisements from nearby devices. So you can't "scan" for a specific device. What you can do is stop scanning (listening) once the device(s) of interest have been found. I believe with `bluepy` this can be done with the `withDelegate` functionality by writing your own [ScanDelegate](https://ianharvey.github.io/bluepy-doc/scanner.html#sample-code) class. Maybe update your question with what you have tried so far and people can look at why it isn't doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks @ukBaz, it seems I just misunderstood how BLE is working. And yes, in this case ScanDelegate class is all I need